# Coger un parámetro de una tabla html sacada de una consulta sql y mostrarlo por echo

Tags: php, javascript

Quiero que, al hacer click en modificar, me coja el $row['idmanager'] y lo meta en una variable php para poder hacer updates en el div que tengo con display none.

```
<?php
include "sesion.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/stilo.css" />
<title>Listado</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="title" content="Registro de cesiones de Striker Manager">
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    .muestro{
            text-decoration:underline;
            cursor:pointer;
        }
        .oculto{
           display:none;
        }
        .visible{
            display:block;
        }

    </style>

     <script type="text-javascript" language="javascript">
    function cogeposiciones(seleccion){
        var posicion=document.getElementById('posicion').value;

    }
    </script>

   <script>
        function mostrar() {
        var formu=document.getElementById("anexo");
        if (formu.className="oculto"){
        formu.className="visible";
        }
        }

       function ocultar() {
        var formu=document.getElementById("anexo");
        if (formu.className="visible"){
        formu.className="oculto";
        }
        }

    </script>

<?php
require("conexion.php");
?>
<?php
if (isset($_GET['posicion'])){
$posicion=$_GET['posicion'];
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM manager WHERE 
posicion='$posicion'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta) > 0)
{
echo "<p>Listado de {$posicion}</p>";
echo " <table border='1px solid black'> <tr> <th>id</th> <th>nick</th> <th>posicion</th> <th>Acciones</th></tr>  ";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{ 
    $linkid=$row['idmanager'];
    $linknick=$row['nick'];
    $linkpos=$row['posicion'];
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td id='getid' name='getid'> ".$row['idmanager']." </td>";
    echo "<td> ".$row['nick']." </td>";
    echo "<td> ".$row['posicion']." </td>";
    echo "<td> <a href='' onclick='mostrar();'>Modificar</a>
    <a href='borrar.php?idmanager=$linkid'>Borrar</a></td>"; 
    echo "</tr>";
}   
echo "</table>";
} 
else 
{ 
    echo " <p>Aún no hay registros en la base de datos</p>";
}
}
?>


<?php
if (isset($_GET['nick'])){
$nick=$_GET['nick'];
$consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM manager WHERE nick LIKE 
'$nick%'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($consulta) > 0)
{
echo "<p>Listado de {$nick}</p>"; //concatenar
echo " <table border='1px solid black'> <tr> <th>id</th> <th>nick</th> <th>posicion</th> </tr>  ";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
{ 
    $linkid=$row['idmanager'];
    echo "<tr>"; 
    echo "<td id='getid' name='getid'> ".$row['idmanager']." </td>";
    echo "<td> ".$row['nick']." </td>";
    echo "<td> ".$row['posicion']." </td>"; 
    echo "<td> <a class='muestro' onclick='mostrar();'>Modificar</a>
    <a href='borrar.php?idmanager=$linkid'>Borrar</a></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}   
echo "</table>";
} 
else 
{ 
    echo " <p>Aún no hay registros en la base de datos</p>";
}
}
?>
<div class="oculto" id="anexo">
    <label for="nick"><input type="text" name="nick">
   <label for="posicion>
        <select id="posicion" name="posicion" required 
onchange="cogeposiciones()">
            <option value="" disabled selected>Selecciona</option>
            <?php
            $sql_select_pos="SELECT posicion FROM posiciones";
            $ejec_select_pos= mysqli_query($conexion, $sql_select_pos) or 
die("No se pudo realizar el select de posiciones");
        while($posiciones=mysqli_fetch_row($ejec_select_pos)){
                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $posiciones[0];?>"><?php echo 
 $posiciones[0];?></option>
                <?php
            }
            ?>

            </select>
<input type="button" value="Ocultar" onclick="ocultar();">
<input type="button" value="Enviar">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El efecto que quiero conseguir es este http://prntscr.com/jniwwk de forma que me aseguro que salga el id que quiero, para después poder usarlo en el update

Answer (score 1):

Yo normalmente lo que hago en estos casos es pasarle el id a la función de editar(en tu caso mostrar()) y quedaría algo así:

```
 echo "<td> <a href='' onclick='mostrar(".$row['idmanager'].");'>Modificar</a></td>";
```

Después lo que haría es en el Javascript pasar los parámetros por POST y con AJAX, y ahí ya operaría con la BD haciendo las consultas y actualizaciones que vayas necesitando.